# How to fill a matrix with data in Fortran 90

Tags: file, matrix, fortran, fortran90

I have an issue, maybe stupid, with a code that I wrote. I generated 30 datasets of 24 lines containing different values that represent, however, the same measure, but I can not print them in array format. Let me explain, I get a single column with all the values, I would be able to write them as a matrix of 24 rows by 30 columns. I tried to read various threads on this site and on others, but I got matrices of zeros alternating with my values, how can I do? The following is the code I wrote with trying to get the matrix "a" formed by the values of "diffu"

```
program deviation
 implicit none

 character(len=20) :: filein,fileout,fileinp
 integer :: row,i,h,io,n,j,l,m,col
 real :: usv,usf,tsv,tsf,su,st
 real :: diffu, difft
 real, dimension(24,30) :: a
 real, dimension(720) :: u
 n = 39
 row = 24
 col = n-9
 write(*,'(2x,''Input file .......''/)')
 read(*,'(a15)') filein
 write(*,'(2x,''Output file........''/)')
 read(*,'(a15)') fileout

 open(unit = 20,File=fileout)

 a = 0.

  fileLoop : do i = 10,n
  fileinp = 'lin*27-'
  write(fileinp, '("lin*27-",I2,".dat")') i
  open(unit = i+40,File=fileinp)
  open(unit = 30,File=filein)

  do j = 1, row
  read(30,*,IOSTAT = io) h,usv,tsv
  read(i+40,*,IOSTAT = io) h,usf,tsf
   if(io/=0) then
    write(*,*) 'End of file!'
   exit
   else if(io==0) then
    diffu = ((usf - usv)**2)
    difft = ((tsf - tsv)**2)
    write(20,*) diffu,difft 

   endif
   enddo
  enddo
 close(i+40)
 close(30)

 enddo fileLoop
 close(20)

 open(unit=20,STATUS='OLD',FILE=fileout)
  do r = 1, 720
  read(20,*,IOSTAT = io) diffu,difft
  u(r) = diffu
  if(io/=0) then
  write(*,*) "Error!"
  exit
  else if(io==0) then
   do m = 1, 24
    do l = 1, col
     a(m,l) = a(m,l) + u(r)

    enddo
   enddo
 endif
 enddo  
 write(*,*) a
 close(20)


end program deviation
```

Comment: move `print,a` outside the loop

Comment: agentp i edited my code, I tried to modified it and close and then re-open the output file, but i obtain the same value of diffu...how can i do?

Comment: You must write to unit 20 which is bound to `fileout`.

Comment: What do you mean Vladimir? I must write a row like this?
read(20,*) fileout